# Protected notice appears at the bottom of the page for guest users and is poorly formatted

Tags: bug, protected-questions

Guests see the *Protected* notice [at the bottom of the page](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/400/please-share-your-hidden-os-x-features-or-tips-and-tricks), somewhat displaced:

[image]

Logged in, all is fine:

[image]

It actually belongs there, at the bottom, but then it has some design glitches, or it needs to be placed at the top.

Verified on Firefox and Chrome stable.

Comment: It at least sits where you expect the answer box to be

Comment: True… not so sure if this is *actually* a bug or if the padding of the post notice is just missing.

Comment: Are you complaining about the notice being at the bottom rather than the top? I'm pretty sure it's at the location of the answer box by design. However, there is indeed a minor design glitch causing the box to slightly overlap the text that follows it on several sites.

Comment: @Gilles Well, I'm not sure. Either it's inconsistent or the layout is broken. You can choose which one is the bug here :)