# Does the protected box placement depend on the browser?

Tags: discussion, bug, design, protected-questions

I just noticed that the protected box in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz/57421#57421) is placed at the bottom page.  Normally, it should be placed right below the question, the same as other boxes (bounty box, duplicate box, etc). The following screenshot proves it.

[image]

However, Joseph Wright said that he still see the box in the same place as the bounty box, etc. Please visit our conversation in the chat [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/12942755#12942755) to know how it was discussed chronologically.

So my question is "Does the protected box placement depend on the browser?".

Comment: It depends on whether you have enough rep to answer the question. For those who are not logged in or have less than 10 rep, the box is placed at the bottom.

Comment: @Antony nope, that was my first thought but now I'm logged in and still see it on bottom. Maybe reputation related?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Ninja edited :)

Comment: @Antony - Nope.. I have 101 rep and still see it at the bottom.

Comment: @Lix Association bonus does not count.

Comment: @Antony - drat :/

Comment: @Lix it appears that [even diamond mods and developers can't answer protected question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202366/eeeek-something-stole-the-protection-why-is-this-protected-question-unprotect#comment643445_202368)! (if they have only the 101 from association bonus :-))

Comment: @ShadowWizard - about time someone tightened their reins ;)

Comment: @Lix: [NOOO](http://i.imgur.com/KtfR4ZG.png) :(

Comment: @AmalMurali - hehehe... How did you get close enough to take that picture!?! So majestic... much horn... wow...