# Why does the protected notice appear at the bottom of the page for me on some sites, instead of the top?

Tags: discussion, design, protected-questions, post-notices

So I join ***Stack Overflow*** for like almost more than a year like this and mostly I found the question that have been protected by **"someone"** will be show like the bottom picture. You can directly see that this question is protected.

[image]

But just now I visited ***Information Security Stack Exchange***, at first I saw the question get a lot attention and have a high vote but I wonder why this question is not protected. So I just keep scrolling down and see the answer but at the bottom of that page I finally seen the protected label.

[image]

(You can see I have a red small rectangle that mark the protected label show at which part.)

So why does ***Information Security Stack Exchange*** was different from the other site? Doesn't each site design should be the same?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Eeeek! Something stole the protection! (Why is this protected question unprotected?)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202366/eeeek-something-stole-the-protection-why-is-this-protected-question-unprotect)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For users with the privilege to answer [protected questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/52764/350567), the banner shows right after the question body.

For users who aren't privileged to answer those questions (or anonymous users), the banner appears at the bottom, replacing the answer form.

So for you, it's because you haven't earned 10 reputation on Information Security (the association bonus doesn't count), and thus can't answer protected questions. That's why you see the banner at the bottom rather than the top, as it is on Stack Overflow where you have enough reputation to answer.

Comment: But I was logged...

Comment: @kit Right, corrected. It seems you don't have the 10 reputation on Security to answer protected questions, so the banner appears at the bottom.

Comment: I see, thanks for the link.