# Why are “protected” questions marked also as “highly active”?

Tags: support, protected-questions

I’ve recently noticed that some questions are marked as “highly active“ while actually they are not.
This is a recent [example](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/536601/an-owner-of-a-large-amount-of-land) of a question that never hit the “Hot Network” list and its total views are, after 3 days, just about 80.

Below the “locked” banner there is another banner which says: ***“Highly active question. You have enough reputation to answer or unprotect this question.***” Which is the same banner used for  real “highly  active questions“!!!

Have conditions for being classified as “highly active questions” changed recently?

Answer (score 6):

> Have conditions for being classified as “highly active questions” changed recently?

The [timeline](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/536601/timeline#history_866ecf42-96f9-4de8-a14d-8ae0495919a3) shows a ♦ moderator chose to protect it manually. This is possible even though there are no deleted answers; perhaps they were afraid of new users posting comments as answers, since the question has a comment lock?

[image]

The name "highly active" may be confusing, but apparently (see the comments by Shog9 [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337053/295232)) it's a nudge to users to protect only those questions which are really "highly active".

---

The strange thing about this situation is that to me (with a mere 12k reputation on EL&U), only the [lock](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22228/295232) banner is shown:

[image]

You do see the banner because you have enough reputation (more than 15k) to [unprotect questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/52764/295232); this is [a deliberate choice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/340845/295232) to reduce noise.

Comment: Thanks for your post. So if I understand it correctly the reason why the mark HAQ is used for “protected” but not HAQ is to attract users to answer the question?