# Move the "highly active question" banner down below the question

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, protected-questions

Maybe it's just me, but the new "highly-active" banner seems kind of jarring:

[image: Screenshot of a question showing the banner]

It feels to me like the most eye-catching thing on the page, positioned as it is above the question text, and yet it's probably irrelevant to me: the average person to arrive on a question just wants to read the content, and doesn't care whether the question is protected or not. I personally find it distracting enough that I'm tempted to unprotect questions just to spare visitors the visual noise.

Why not move the banner down - for instance, below the question...

[image: Screenshot of an alternative layout I'm suggesting]

... or even all the way to the answer box:

[image: Screenshot of yet another alternative layout]

(One compromise might be to show it below the question for users who don't have enough rep to answer a protected question - since it's potentially valuable for them to know that immediately if they're only reading the question because they're considering answering it - but to show it above the answer box for the rest of us. But I think either option would be preferable to how it's positioned now.)

Comment: related: [Remove or make "Highly active question" post notice less visible / annoying](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337708/remove-or-make-highly-active-question-post-notice-less-visible-annoying)

Comment: I set to completed as we implemented a different change to this functionality that will remove the banner for those users for whom it is not actionable. I know that this does not fulfill the actual request, but in my opinion it does fulfill the intention.

Comment: Related: [Why does the protected notice appear at the bottom of the page for me on some sites, instead of the top?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/332759/335251), [Eeeek! Something stole the protection! (Why is this protected question unprotected?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/202366/335251) – The latter bug report was made at at Jon Ericson’s request while he was a CM, and Jon answered it, noting that its overall positioning was intended behavior but saying he didn’t know why the banner was awkwardly placed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Meta post announcing the launch of the Post Notice redesign:

[New Post Notices are live network-wide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339700/new-post-notices-are-live-network-wide)

> #### I feel like the old notices did X better, can I get that back please?
>
> The old notices are gone for good. And the main structure of the new notices is not going to be changing for the time being **(so no, we aren't going to move some of them back down to the bottom of the question)** That said, we are open to hearing all suggestions. Make a case for how we can fit your needs into the new notices (taking into account that any changes that we make need to also work in the context of notices that are seen by millions of people every month).

Comment: Argh! I'd honestly rather unprotect everything I see than live with these in their current locations. The noisy banner bugs me more than bad answers would. :(

Comment: @MarkAmery very much agree. Follow along [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/337708/281934) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/339709/281934).

Comment: It is particularly annoying when I have already answered the question.  Why are you telling me less than I already know?  is my immediate, irritated thought.

Answer (score 5):

The Highly Active Question banner is now only shown to users who either do not have enough rep to answer (10 earned rep), or who have enough rep to unprotect (15K earned rep).

Users who are in between these two privilege levels (and thus are able to answer, but can't do anything about the protected status) are no longer shown this banner.